# Switch on GPS automatically without user interaction

Tags: ios

Is it possible to switch on the GPS programmatically, without user interaction?

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to turn on GPS without user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you attempt to switch it on, there will be an Alert.  After user has enabled it , then you can switch on/off at will.

see CLLocationManager

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html